# Need help on Highest and Lowest (codewars)

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm stuck on an edge case in a coding challenge: would be great if someone could help;

In this little assignment you are given a string of space separated numbers, and have to return the highest and lowest number.

Example:

```
highAndLow("1 2 3 4 5"); // return "5 1"
highAndLow("1 2 -3 4 5"); // return "5 -3"
highAndLow("1 9 3 4 -5"); // return "9 -5"
```

Notes:

All numbers are valid Int32, no need to validate them.
There will always be at least one number in the input string.
Output string must be two numbers separated by a single space, and highest number is first.

Here is my code in Javascript:

```
function highAndLow(numbers){
  numbers2=numbers.split(' ');
  var highest =parseInt(numbers2[0]);
  var lowest =parseInt(numbers2[0]);
  if (numbers2.length==1) {
    return numbers;
  }
  else {
    for (i=0;i<numbers2.length;i++) {
      if (parseInt(numbers2[i])>highest) {
        highest = parseInt(numbers2[i]);
      }
      else if (parseInt(numbers2[i])<lowest) {
        lowest = parseInt(numbers2[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return(highest + " " + lowest);
}
```

I can pass 17 tests but am stuck on an Expected '42 42' because I am returning '42' which is puzzling to me. Any help appreciated :]

Comment: What numbers are you passing which cause a problem? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just add `<=` and `>=` instead of `>` and `<`so the both conditions are satisfied

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by sorting the array and then choosing the first and last element from the sorted array.

```
function highestAndLowest(nums) {
  let numbers = nums.split(' ');
  let sorted = numbers.sort(function (a, b) {
    return Number(a) - Number(b);
  });
  return sorted[0] + " " + sorted[sorted.length - 1];
}
```

https://jsbin.com/farapep/edit?js,console

This can be faster depending on the browsers sort implementation, the size of the array, and the initial order of the array.

Comment: @Jonasw you're right, I made that claim without proof.  After looking into it further there are various factors that could make it faster or slower, depending on the size of the array, the browsers sort implementation, and the initial order of the array.  I've updated the answer to reflext that.

Comment: if the for loop is optimized well, weve got O(n) for the OPs code and ~O(2n) for yours. But youre right, the browsers optimization can surprise one ...

Comment: Additionally you have to take into account the number of comparisons made. For arrays less than 10 elements, Chrome uses insertion sort which on average has 1/4 * (N^2 - N) comparisons, where OPs will have N^2 comparisons made.  Also in terms of asymptotic complexity O(n)=O(2n) but that this point that's nit picking.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work well just like this

```
function highAndLow(numbers){
  numbers = numbers.split(" ");
  return Math.max(...numbers) +" "+ Math.min(...numbers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (numbers2.length==1) {
  return numbers;
}
```

That means if just "42" passed, you return "42". Thats not required here. Just remove that and it should work. How i would write it:

```
function getMaxMin(numbers){
  numbers = numbers.split(" ");
  return Math.max(...numbers) +" "+ Math.min(...numbers);
}
```

or your code a bit beautified:

```
function getMaxMin(numbers){
  var max,min;
  numbers = numbers.split(" ");
  for( var num of numbers ){
    if( !max || num > max ) max = num;
    if( !min || num < min ) min = num;
  }
  return max+" "+min;
}
```

Comment: forget the conversion, like `".map(n => +n)`, because you get a valid input of numbers, Int32 (which works well with `min`/`max`). and even if you have to make a conversion, then you could take `Number` as callback.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin

```
 fun highAndLow(numbers: String): String {
        val s =  numbers.split(" ").sorted()
        return "${s.last()} ${s.first()}"
    }
```

or in one line

```
fun highAndLow(numbers: String): String = numbers.split(" ").sorted().run { "${first()} ${last()}" }
```

Answer (score -1):

Let us consider the given example:

highAndLow("1 2 3 4 5"); // return "5 1"

On calling function highAndLow with arguments ("1 2 3 4 5"), output should be "5 1".

So my function takes the argument. Each number is picked upon on the basis of space between them(used split method). I have used ParseInt to specify the datatype, because var can be anything(string/integer). The algorithm used is very basic one which considers the first number as the maximum and compares its with the rest of the arguments. Value of max is updated if it finds a number greater than itself. Same algorithm is used for min value also. The return statement is designed to get the value in specific way as mentioned in the example.

```
function highAndLow(numbers){
  num=numbers.split(' ');
  var max = parseInt(num[0]);
  var min = parseInt(num[0]);
  for (var i = 0; i <= num.length; i++) {
    if(parseInt(num[i]) > max){
      max = parseInt(num[i]);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i <= num.length; i++) {
    if(parseInt(num[i]) < min){
      min = parseInt(num[i]);
    } 
 }
 return (max + " " + min);
}
```

You can also use inbuilt methods min and max. I wanted to solve this question without using them.

Comment: Could add more explanation?

Comment: I have added explanation. Please let me know if this helps.